# Python : Build the differents paths/trees from a xml file

Tags: python, xml, path, elementtree

Here is an example of a xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ADD_LandIndex_001>
      <CNTROLAREA>
        <BSR>
          <status>ADD</status>
          <NOUN>LandIndex</NOUN>
          <REVISION>001</REVISION>
        </BSR>
      </CNTROLAREA>
      <DATAAREA>
        <LandIndex>
          <reportId>AMI100031</reportId>
          <requestKey>R3278458</requestKey>
          <SubmittedBy>EN4871</SubmittedBy>
          <submittedOn>2015/01/06 4:20:11 PM</submittedOn>
          <LandIndex>
            <agreementdetail>
              <agreementid>001       4860</agreementid>
              <agreementtype>NATURAL GAS</agreementtype>
              <currentstatus>
                <status>ACTIVE</status>
                <statuseffectivedate>1965/02/18</statuseffectivedate>
                <termdate>1965/02/18</termdate>
              </currentstatus>
              <designatedrepresentative>
              </designatedrepresentative>
            </agreementdetail>
          </LandIndex>
        </LandIndex>
      </DATAAREA>
    </ADD_LandIndex_001>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I would like to store in a list all the differents paths that have a text in my xml file. So I would like something like that :

```
['Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_01/CNTROLAREA/BSR/status', 'Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_01/CNTROLAREA/BSR/LandIndex', ...]
```

I try a little code that does not work. I don't see how to take seperatly the last elements of one branch and how to all the path from the beginning when I switch of node in the middle (i.e `Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_01/DATAAREA...`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os
import pandas as pd
from re import search

filename = 'file_try.xml'
element_tree = et.parse(filename)
root = element_tree.getroot()
namespace = "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}"


def remove_namespace(string,namespace) :
    
    if search(namespace, string) :
        new_string = string.replace(namespace,'')
    else : 
        new_string= string
    return new_string

dico = {}
title = root.tag
print(title)

for element in root.findall('.//') :
    #print(element)
    if len(list(element)) > 0 :
        #print('True ') 
        title= remove_namespace(title + '/' + element.tag, namespace)
        print(title+ '\n')

    else :
        
        title = root.tag
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this for you actual code, but basically - it should look like this:

```
from lxml import etree
soap = """[your xml above]"""
root = etree.XML(soap.encode())    
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for target in root.xpath('//text()'):
    if len(target.strip())>0:       
        print(tree.getpath(target.getparent()).replace('SOAP-ENV:',''))
```

Output:

```
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/status
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/NOUN
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/REVISION
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/reportId
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/requestKey
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/SubmittedBy
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/submittedOn
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/agreementid
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/agreementtype
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/status
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/statuseffectivedate
/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/termdate
```

Comment: Thank you @Jack Fleeting for your answer, it helps me a lot, I wish I would have your skills ! How do you import the data from a xml file in a directory for your variable 'soap' ?

Comment: Sorry, I just found how to do it with : 
`with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    soap = f.read()`

Comment: How you saw, I did a previous post on that, I would like to have now another list that gets the text/content of these paths (elements). I can't find the way to do it with this library lxml, I tried `.text()` or text_content()` but i get an error: the goal is then to have that on a dataframe to export on excel. What is the function or the line to get the content ?

Code :

`for target in root.xpath('//text()'):

    if len(target.strip())>0:       
        path = tree.getpath(target.getparent()).replace('SOAP-ENV:','')
        data = target.text()
        mylist_path.append(path)`

Comment: @Maikiii Glad it worked for you! As to the other thing, Stack Overflow policy says you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: @ Jack, thank you for the information, I redo a new qpost

Comment: Good; once you post it, I'll be happy to take a look at it. Also, if we are done with this one, don't forget to accept the answer please.